# Change redirect of login and logout asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have put my Default.aspx in a folder and now when I login with a user it redirects me to the Default.aspx in the root folder (which doesn't exist) so I get a resource not found error. Also when I do log out I just get redirected to the root folder.
How do I fix this so I get redirected to the proper location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the built in asp.net Membership authentication, then within your web.config, there will be a section which allows you to specify the `defaultUrl` which is as the default `Redirect` after Log In or Log Out.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="[Spefify Page Here]" />
</authentication>
```

Alternatively, you can use `Response.Redirect` to specify the page within your code.

Comment: This worked for Log In but Log Out still redirects me to the Directory Listing of the root page. (btw yes I am using the built in authentication)

Comment: What is the URL of your `loginUrl`? I can't remember if this is what is used for the LogOut.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Default/Default.aspx" />
</authentication>

Comment: It was like this originally i just added the defaultUrl.

Comment: Nevermind i found it. It is in the site master under LoggedInTemplate (LogoutPageUrl="~/").

Comment: Are you using the LoginStatus control? If so, there is a `LogoutPageUrl` which you specify.

Answer (score 1):

When `login` and `logout`, in the respective pages, you can use `Response.Redirect` Method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
Response.Redirect("link_of_your_desired_location", false);
```

Comment: If I do that then it doesn't actually log in the user it just redirects to the Default page when clicking the Log In button.

Comment: You need to call the `method` after inserting necessary information to your session variables so that the user can be treated as `logged in`